# Can the string coupling constant be written in Planck units?

Tags: string-theory, dimensional-analysis, spacetime-dimensions, physical-constants

The relationship between string units and Planck units can be written as $l_p^{24} = l_s^{24}g_s^2$, where $g_s$ is the string coupling constant.

It then seems like the $g_s$ always must be a mix between Planck and string units? Can $g_s$ be expressed only in Planck units?

Comment: If by Planck units you mean the Planck energy scale $M_p$ or $\ell_p$, then of course not: how are you going to form a dimensionless constant which isn't just 1?

Comment: Are you saying that the string coupling constant is dimensionless?

Comment: @JohanHansen String coupling is dimensionless.

Answer (score 0):

No, as the coupling constant $g$ is dimensionless.

You can express in terms of the expectation value of the dilaton field, as $g = e^{<\phi>}$.